# How can I disable an anchor href with target _blank?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have this HTML line:

```
<a href="<%url%>" target="_blank">link</a>
```

Where `<%url%`> is a token I have to replace with a value that produces the click to do absolutely nothing. Note the anchor is in an iframe with the top same domain.

Consider:

1. I really do have to use an anchor
2. I have tried with the values `#`
   and `javascript:void(0)` but since the target is `_blank` they
   change the `top.location.href` to the iframe `window.location.href`
   so the iframe is loaded as the top window
3. I can't modify the HTML except for the token
4. No jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the way:

```
javascript:void(this.onclick=function(){return false;})
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you add attribute

```
onclick="return false;"
```

?

Comment: I can't modify the HTML except for the token

Comment: In that case can you modify url to be " onclick="return false; ?

Comment: The problem is I can't be sure that the html is comming with double quotes. It has to support both situations.

Answer (score 0):

If you can put any string into the token, then make it end the href, then also include an onclick that cancels the click.  Try replacing the token with this:

```
#" onclick="return false;
```

Comment: The problem is I can't be sure that the html is comming with double quotes. It has to support both situations.